What does the magnetic permeability of real materials look like and why?
I am currently taking a graduate electromagnetism I course. In this course, we are discussing electromagnetic waves in dielectric media. We assume that $\mu$ is constant but that $\epsilon$ is not. At first, it seemed like we assume $\mu$ is constant for simplicity but upon asking the Professor about this assumption, he described it as being based in empirical reality.
So, can $\mu$ really be treated as constant for most materials? Why or why not? I do not mean to ask for an entire course in condensed matter theory; rather, I would appreciate some heuristic descriptions of why one would expect $\mu$ to be constant (or not) for most materials.

do you mean constant relative to spatial coordinates?

B-H curves of, e.g. Metglas, are a function of frequency. See, e.g., https://www.netl.doe.gov/sites/default/files/netl-file/METGLAS-2605-SA1-Core-Datasheet_approved%5B1%5D.pdf

Dielectric are generally good insulators which implies a large band gap. This means that the valence bands are filled, which in turn means that spins are paired up and orbital angular momentum has been canceled out. Without angular momentum, you don't have magnetic dipoles to respond to a magnetic field. Being an insulator, the material also doesn't have conduction electrons to flow in response to an EM field, so there won't be a source of magnetization. That covers the potential sources of strong magnetization.
You might imagine that the electric field could cause the nonconduction charges to oscillate and create a magnetizing field. I guess someone should show that magnetization is small in some toy model when compared to electric polarization. But, empirically, it's true in dielectrics.
